# Error in non existent global.asa

Tags: security, iis-6, windows-server-2003, global.asa

I have a user's website giving an error in a global.asa file but it does not exist in their web root. It looks like the account has been hacked as it's giving an error about not connecting to a server, and at the same time I see the firewall block outbound connection requests.

```
 msxml3.dll error '80072efd'

 A connection with the server could not be established

/LM/W3SVC/6510/ROOT/global.asa, line 66
```

I've deleted the IIS instance and had the control panel recreate it, but the issue still exists. I've even created a dummy asp file which only displays some text and it happens.

I'm at a loss where this could be being picked up and looking for suggestions. Where might this be set?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem on a w2k3 server (iis6) with many sites, where just one had the fake global.asa;
I've not still found cause but a workaround solution, for me, has been:

- open MMC Console (IIS manager)
- stop IIS
- double click on Web Sites (confirm reload offline configuration)
- under every site delete "ghost" global.asa (that you don't find under phisical websites folder)
- start IIS